# AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list and pageToken

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I've been trying to put together a simple google app script to generate a list of all our Calendar resources (I have other ideas of what to do once I get the data) and for whatever reason, when I try the standard do while, the page tokens seem to increment indefinitely.  I've written many similar scripts, but this is the first time I'm using AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list and as far as I can see, this is an undocumented bug (or I'm doing something wrong and just not spotting it).

Here's an example.  I'm a super admin, so it's using my credentials and it just continuously loops over the same data.

```
function listAllCalendars() {
var calendars, pageToken;
do {
  calendars = AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list("my_customer");
  if (calendars.items && calendars.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < calendars.items.length; i++) {
      var calendar = calendars.items[i];
      Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', calendar.resourceId, calendar.resourceName, calendar.resourceDescription);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No calendars found.');
  }
  pageToken = calendars.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);
}
```

Here's another example, without a do while.  This will return 100 results and only 100 results (I've tried a couple of different values for maxResults but 100 results is all it will return).

```
function getAllCalendars(){
var calendars = AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list("my_customer");
Logger.log(calendars.items.length);
  if (calendars.items && calendars.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < calendars.items.length; i++) {
      var calendar = calendars.items[i];
      Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', calendar.resourceId, calendar.resourceName, calendar.resourceDescription);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No calendars found.');
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apps Script, the the Calendar list method, takes the following objects:

list(**String customer, Object optionalArgs**)

The string customer will be your domain or my_customer.

For the **optionalArgs**, you can specify the maxResults and the pageToken.

You were missing the optional arguments as part of the list method.

I updated your code to include the optional arguments. It should work now.

Hope this helps :-)

```
function listAllCalendars() {

var calendars, pageToken;

do {

  var arguments = {
      maxResults: 200,
      pageToken: pageToken
    }; 
  calendars = AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list("my_customer",arguments);
  if (calendars.items && calendars.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < calendars.items.length; i++) {
      var calendar = calendars.items[i];
      Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', calendar.resourceId, calendar.resourceName, calendar.resourceDescription);       
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No calendars found.');
  }
  pageToken = calendars.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jose for the feedback and for spotting the problem with my code.  What's interesting is that my original code, did include arguments, but my test code here did not.